# Render react icon/component <select> tag in react/editor-js plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I wanted to show a personIcon (named as  in the code) in place of "aa" select tag. When i click on that icon, i should see the option of select. Moreover, the select icon should be replaced with the selected option icon (so that icon has to dynamic).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY4Kc.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOQYx.png)
How can i dispaly an icon in select tag.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0EFQ.png)

Comment: To get good answer, it helps to post good questions. Here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask